# react js does history.push and history.goBack re mounts previous page/component?

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-navigation

I want to store my component where I call API and get data in stack, so on pushing new component and then going back it should maintain it's state.

I am not using any package for navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save this data, I may suggest you to store it using redux, or using react context

Comment: So there isn't a way to keep components in stack memory?

Comment: @PrafulKadam without special packages, there is no proper way to do this.

Comment: Thanks @Nikita Prokofyev, Basically I was looking for a way where on back, componentDidMount() won't get called. It happens by default in native mobile apps, not sure about web apps.

Comment: in web apps it fires every time when component get unmounted and mounted again

Comment: Thanks, for confirming.